# creating dynamic lists with configured values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Am trying to create dynamically generated lists depending on the configured value and needs a specific key for each list for example

configured value is 4
and list of numbers are [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] then this should be converted to

```
 key    list
-----------------
4      [1,2,3,4]
8      [5,6,7,8]
12     [9]
```

If configured value is 4 then always 1234 should be in first list and 5678 in second list
If the values are [1,2,3,6,7,8,9] then the result should be

```
key    list
-----------------
4      [1,2,3]
8      [6,7,8]
12     [9]
```

Tried below code and am able to create list but not the key. Also feels coded many lines to create the list.

```
def dicttest(data):
    data.sort()
    result = pd.DataFrame({'ids': data})
    howmany = 4
    listcount = (result['ids'].max() // howmany) + 1
    lists = []
    for x in range(listcount):
        lists.append(x * howmany)
    result['range'] = pd.cut(result.ids, lists, precision=0).astype(str)
    result = result.groupby('range').ids.apply(list).reset_index()

    return result
```

getting below result

```
range    ids
---------------
(0,4]    [1,2,3]
(4,8]    [6,7,8]
nan      [9]
```

It will be ok to get the result in dataframe OR dictionary with key and list of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to get `key` and perform your operation

You can simply calculate each number floor-divided by 4, and group by that. No need for `pd.cut`. (Though there is some complexity as show below to ensure value `4` is in row with key `4` and value `8` is in row with key `8`, etc.)

```
def dicttest(data, howmany = 4):
    data.sort()
    result = pd.DataFrame({'sites': data})
    result['key'] = ((result['sites']-1) // howmany  + 1) * howmany 
    result = result.groupby('key').sites.apply(list)
    return result.to_dict()
```

The operation `((result['sites']-1) // 4 + 1) * 4` makes sure the value `4` in the list is placed in group with key `4`.
The operation does `(4-1) // 4 + 1) * 4` `=> 4`.
For the 1st row, the key becomes ((1-1)// 4 + 1) * 4 = 4`

Output:

```
>>> dicttest([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], howmany=4)
{4: [1, 2, 3, 4], 8: [5, 6, 7, 8], 12: [9]}
```

Comment: Did not understand the line ((result['sites']-1) // 4 + 1) * 4. the operation (result['sites']-1) will become 0 for first row, 1 for 2nd row 2 for 3rd row and so on right? And also is there any way  to get a dictionary instead dataframe?

Comment: yes (result['sites']-1) will become 0 for 1st row, but then we add back 1 before multiplying by 4, so it will be ((0 // 4) + 1)*4 = 4. let me update the answer to return a dictionary instead.